# Specific Heat Capacity of Heavy Water

Tags: thermodynamics, water, hydrogen, hydrogen-bond, isotope

Water has an unusually high specific heat capacity due to it's hydrogen bonds.

Why is it that the change in isotope causes a 10% difference in the heat capacity? How does the added neutron in the nucleus make any difference to the bonds?

Comment: Googling 'heat capacity of heavy water' yields various scholarly reports dating back to the 1930s.

Comment: True, but the ones I've looked at are extremely long with lots of equations I can't make sense of, so an understandable answer would be nicer if possible... Should I edit the question?

Comment: The Wikipedia page (3rd hit for me from Google) on 'Orders_of_magnitude_(specific_heat_capacity)' lists Water as 4186 J/kg/K and Heavy water as 3767 J/kg/K - so it makes about a 10% difference.

Comment: Thank you! I just realised I messed up and the edit I put in after your first comment didn't show up. I've improved the question now, I hope it's better!

Comment: The added mass of a deuteron relative to a proton reduces the O-D stretch vibration frequency relative to O-H. This reduces the energy that can go in to that degree of freedom, reducing the heat capacity.

Comment: I agree with Jon Custer. A far I know the added neutron will not change the Schrodinger equation. So electronic contribution is same for them but mass has effect on vibrational frequency. You can also look for KIE (kinetic isotope effect) in the standard computational chemistry literature.

Comment: Specific heat capacity // H2O: 74.539 J mol-1 K-1 // D2O: 84.42 J mol-1 K-1 // http://www1.lsbu.ac.uk/water/water_properties.html // So "heavy water" takes more energy to heat than "normal" water.

Comment: @JonCuster I may be wrong, but around room temperature, do vibrational degrees of freedom really contribute to heat capacity? Additionally,  I think the increased mass of the deuterium atoms would increase the energy stored in the rotational degrees of freedom, which would actually increase the heat capacity of $\ce{D2O}$, as suggested by MaxW's link (which I trust more, given the background of the site).

Comment: The values on Wikipedia seem to be the same on a per mol basis, which leads me to believe someone just took the same molar heat capacity for both as an approximation, and converted to the specific heat capacities according to their respective molar masses masses

Comment: The heat capacity per mole is higher for heavy water. The hydrogen bonding is stronger.

Answer (score 4):

I posted an answer here the other day which was completely wrong! I apologise and have left the incorrect text below for posterity to record how wrong people who should know better can be!

Looking on the NIST fluid properties database I see that the specific heat capacity (i.e. the heat capacity per unit mass) of D2O is just 1.5% higher than the specific heat capacity of H2O. So at 298 K this makes the molar heat capacity of D2O (84.963 J/K/mol) an astonishing 12.7% higher than H2O (75.38 J/K/mol). I am astounded and have no explanation.

## Everything below this line is WRONG!

*The molar heat capacity is almost exactly the same. i.e. it takes the same energy to heat the same number of molecules by one degree Celsius. 
The difference in the *specific* heat is just because of the difference in density. D2O molecules have a relative molar mass of about 20 compared with 18 for H2O. Since the bond lengths are similar, the density is higher by a factor 20/18 - about 11% higher. So a given mass of D2O has about 11% fewer molecules in it.*

Comment: According to this page http://www1.lsbu.ac.uk/water/water_properties.html the molar heat capacity of D2O is more than 10% higher than H2O. Are these values wrong then?

Comment: I will check with some independent sources and get back to you. The 'internet' seems to have specific heat capacities i.e. per unit mass that are within 1.5% of the light water value (e.g. http://hedhme.com/content_map/?link_id=22146) . That is the level of change I would have expected for the molar heat capacity. It seems suspicious to me that the molar heat capacity should change by almost the factor as the density. As it happends, this answer really matters to me (!) but I think I need more reliable sources than are openly available on line.

Comment: Hi. I was completely wrong. I apologise. I have changed the original post to reflect that.